# Image Build Action: Difference between None and Embedded Resource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I use pictures over some of my buttons and I don't want these images included in the output.

These images are set through the buttons properties, so they are defined in the Resource.resx file.

I was told to set the Build Action to Embedded Resource, but I'm curious as to why this makes a difference. I have the build action set to "None" right now, and none of the files are set to copy. And I can move the built application anywhere and launch it and all the images show just fine. (Just to clarify, the images are definitely not in the directory of the program when it's launching, and they still appear just fine).

I looked it up on the MSDN and got this:

> None - The file is not included in the project output group and is not
>   compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains
>   documentation, such as a Readme file.
>
> Embedded Resource - This file is
>   embedded in the main project build output as a DLL or executable. It
>   is typically used for resource files.

But from this is sounds like having them all set at None shouldn't even be working (but it does).

So I'm curious as to what benefit setting it to Embedded Resource gives. I did test it out, and there was no difference. Was hoping someone could explain what's happening.

My only assumption is that when setting the image property through the button and the entry gets added to the resource file, it's in no way connected to the file added to the project (even though they're the same). So if you're setting the image property this way, do the images not even need to be included in the project (i.e. in the solution explorer).

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you have stumbled over two different ways of displaying an image.

1. If you use a resource file then the resource file itself will
   contain the images and that file will be copied into the output directory. You will
   then reference the image out of this resource file and all will be
   well. The actual image setting for none/embedded/content will not
   matter. This allows you to create resource files for a variety of
   languages and locations and change which image is used based on your
   applications culture.
2. The other way to reference an image is by either embedding it or
   setting it as content in the project.  If you set it as content it
   will copy to the output directory and can be referenced physically
   based on location or if you embed it the file will be located inside
   the dll that is created and you can pull a resource stream with that
   file in it using built in functions.

You are using method #1 so once you have put it in the resource file you don't have to have it in the project since the resource file is in the project already and that is where the file will come from.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was confused about. In my head when I was setting the image source all it was doing was mapping to where the image would be when the program was launched. I wasn't grasping what happened when it was added into the resource file. All has been made clear.